# Append to beginning of list

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that lists the source files: (shortened to relevant)

```
SRCFOLDER=src/
SOURCES= main.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

and I would like to concate the strings together, but for each one in `SOURCES`. As you can see above, I do it for `OBJECTS`, but I want to do it like this: (pseudocode)

```
foreach(src in SOURCES)
  src = concate(SRCFOLDER, src)
```

so that if `SOURCES` was `main.cpp window.cpp`, the result would be `src/main.cpp src/window.cpp`.

I tried this:

```
SOURCES=$(SOURCES:*=$(SRCFOLDER)/*)
```

but I get this error:

```
makefile:12: *** Recursive variable `SOURCES' references itself (eventually). Stop.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SRCFOLDER := src
SOURCES := main.cpp window.cpp
SOURCES := $(addprefix $(SRCFOLDER)/, $(SOURCES))
```